# Using LIKE and ? to find characters at specific position in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following two strings in a DNA field in Access:

GGCTAG

ACGCT

I am attempting to use SQL to find only the 'CT' at the end of the second string due to its place in the string. This would ignore the 'CT' in the first string. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnDNA_Click()
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT LastName FROM Patient WHERE PatientID = 1"

Me!txtDisease1.Value = DLookup("LastName", "Patient", "DNA LIKE '???ct*'")

End Sub
```

Can anyone find what is wrong with the code? The issue appears to be with the '?' because the textbox will populate with information if I just use:

```
LIKE 'ct*'
```

But it is the wrong information.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the asterisk to the beginning.

```
LIKE '*ct'
```

Also, you do realize the strSQL that you build does nothing in the code right? And that the DLookup just finds whichever patient is the first in the table that matches that pattern?

Comment: Another way could be: `"RIGHT(DNA,2)='ct'"`

Comment: Yeah I forgot that I left strSQL in there, I'm not using it. I moved the asterisk to the front but the code still doesn't care how many question marks I use. The query should fail if there isn't three question marks but it doesn't.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the behavior of the asterisk. If I put it in front it returns the second string, if I put it in the back and the front it returns the first string.

Comment: I don't have any question marks in my code. Question marks don't do anything in Access.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken about the question marks. I was thinking of SQL Server

Comment: I was told that question marks are the Access equivalent of an underscore to specify how many characters into the string you want the query to look. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: But if you're just looking for strings ending in CT, you just need the asterisk at the front and don't need any question marks.